# how to set my zip extractor app as default in mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, unzip

I am Developing Zip extractor cocoa app so my question is how do i make it as default app(programatically) for all .zip files.

Any suggestion.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Reopening this question. It was originally marked as a duplicate, but that solution doesn't work with the macOS Sandbox.

Answer (score -1):

1. Select any zip file in Finder
2. right-Click on it with mouse
3. Select Open With submenu
4. Choose Other... menu item
5. Find and select your zip exractor
6. Check Always Open with...  checkbox
   (additionally click Options if you do not see this checkbox)
7. Click Open

Comment: i am asking how to do programatically.